# Cannot restore backup on SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a backup of a SQL database, and it is 409 MB.

When I try to restore it says:

> Restore failed for Server 'SPLYF-R3K8G8JL2\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
>   
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476
>   
> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB per database.

Comment: PS how is it that you have the same machine name as this guy, who posted this same error message SIX YEARS AGO? Seems an odd coincidence. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/c5936ec5-0468-4466-86c5-5ee524213af1/#c5936ec5-0468-4466-86c5-5ee524213af1

Answer (score 4):

(1) it seems like you are trying to restore a SQL Server 2008 R2 database on an instance of SQL Server 2005. You can't go backwards like that.

(2) SQL Server 2005 Express had a limit of 4GB per database. With 2008 R2, the limit is 10GB.

(Note that the size of the backup file is not necessarily the size of the database. The backup file does not include empty space, so if your MDF is >4GB (and mostly empty) the limitation is still enforced, since the limitation is on data file size, and not on backup size or actual data.)

So, the solution is: install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition, and you should be able to restore your database there (assuming it is < 10GB).

If your data file is currently > 10GB but there is < 10GB of data in it, you can:

- in the source instance (or after attaching to a different edition without this limitation), since it seems like there is far less data than 10GB, reduce the data file size using DBCC SHRINKFILE to something less than 10GB.
- take another backup
- proceed with the attach to Express

Comment: I am running it on SQL server Express 2008 with management tools. My actual database is 11GB, I compressed it to 300MB in the kanika.bak file.

Comment: @user1314341 if your database is 11GB, you cannot restore it on SQL Server Express. No version of SQL Server Express will support an 11GB database, regardless of how much you were able to compress the backup. Perhaps you should look at Developer Edition (~$49) or grab Evaluation Edition, attach your database, clear out some data and adjust the data file size, then take another backup.

Comment: I wanted to clarify onething. I have already cleared lots of data and now my kanika.bak file is just 409MB. Still I am getting this error.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the backup file. You need to make sure the data file (the .MDF file, not the .BAK file) is < 10 GB. SQL Server Express doesn't care if the file is empty, it simply won't create a data file (or set of data files) > 10 GB, even if there is *no* data.

Comment: I followed the following steps   1.) Created the new database named CMSDB. 2.) Gave the size of database to 600MB 3.) Right click on databases and selected restore database option 4.) selected the CMSDB as destination database 5) kanika.bak as file for restore 5) Selected the overwrite the  existing database(with replace option.

Comment: And that tries to overwrite your new database with a database that has a data file > 10GB. I don't know how many ways I can explain this to you - you need to fix the source database *before* taking a backup. Your current backup is going to try to restore a file that is greater than 10GB, regardless of whether that is trying to replace a 600 MB database or a 600 GB database. Either fix the database and take a new backup, or move up from Express.

Comment: My datasource is empty, the new database that i created does not have any content. Its a blank database

Comment: I am working on a CMS project, I want to transfer the content which they have in their production database to my development database. So I took the backup of the content from their database in compressed form in kanika.bak file. Now I am trying to use the same file to transfer the contents to me development database which I need to set

Comment: I don't have any new answers for you based on that information. You need to fix the data file so that it is < 10 GB by restoring it to an instance that supports > 10 GB, shrinking the data file, and taking another backup. Or restoring it to an instance that supports > 10 GB and using a schema comparison tool to make your new, empty database match the structure.

Comment: I need the data from their production database to run the CMS project locally.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Inaugural SO Purple Heart awarded.  Phrase officially coined.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I just checked the size og data file (.mdf) it is 3 MB, The backup file is 400MB, I am not able to find what is causing this error

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?

Database backups are often compressed: it's not a surprise that this backup would create a database larger than 4 GB, the limit for SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server 2005 Express.

Try upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: I downloaded and installed SQL Server Express from website http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650 (SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe). So if my backup is just 409MB as i can see the size. how can I rectifiy this error